# PHP email suffix using CONCAT()

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

Trying to use a php generating the email address using the ID eg: peopleID from database using query function with people_mysql into an HTML table with array of emails from five people. The database do not have email addresses only peopleID in a field. Email suffix is @dot.com.

To explain better to what I'm talking about.

```
$peopleid = "12345";
$suffix = "@dot.com";
$email = $peopleid . $suffix;
// where $email then contains "people@dot.com" with MySQL
```

This is what I've come up with with string operator.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM 'people';
mysql> SELECT *, CONCAT('peopleID', '@dot.com') AS 'Email' FROM 'people';
```

I would be grateful if anyone can come a php code.

Comment: Hem, I'd like to help, but honestly I don't understand what you're asking :(

Comment: Okay, your PHP works... what's the problem exactly?

Comment: Ok. I've people staff number for one person is 12345 and in a database you see peopleID 12345. There is no email address in a database. In order to GET a query from database to html page with a list of email address with one example 12345@dot.com. There will be up to ten people on a list return at the same time using peopleID array.

Comment: minitech: Ok I see it works and how do I incorporate as an array of email addresses from all peopleID in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has a mistake in it. Look at the character just before the @ symbol. It should be a single quote.

```
$emails = array();
$query = "SELECT *, CONCAT('peopleID', '@dot.com') AS 'Email' FROM 'people'";
$result = mysql_query($query,$conn_to_database);

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)):
    $emails[] = $row->Email;
endwhile;
```

MySQL queries return a reference to the results, not the results themselves. So, you then need to fetch each row and perform any actions you need to perform. In this case, you are populating and array named $emails that you can then use in your php code.

Comment: Rather, it's the only single quote; the *rest of them* are incorrect.

Comment: The character directly before the @ symbol

Comment: Will this show results as email array? or do I need to anything in field in a database?

Comment: No, you will need to iterate through the results (usually using a while statement) and populate an array from the results

Comment: Can you clarify please? I'm not sure that I understand. If so, can you give example "populate an array from the results", please?

Comment: Thank you for editing the code above. So the results will collect all peopleID staff numbers in PEOPLE column field. There will be about ten staff numbers and will I be able to generate ten staff emails using staff number with email suffix as a result?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You will have all the addresses in the $emails array to use as you see fit.

Comment: Is there a way that I can a limit of MySQL queries return a reference to the results, not the result themselves. For example, limit to ten emails '$email' LIMIT 10'.

Comment: Do you mean to limit the number of results from the query? If yes, then you have it right (LIMIT 10). You would add this after 'people' in your current query.

Comment: $query = "SELECT *, CONCAT('peopleID', '@dot.com') AS 'Email' FROM 'people' 'LIMIT 10'";

Comment: That is correct. If this information has solved your problem, please accept it as right answer so your question will not remain as unanswered

Comment: Look up towards the top of the answer. There is a gray check mark. Click it and it will turn green.